# New fixture old ceiling electric box

Tags: light-fixture, light

Trying to replace an old chandelier fixture. The wiring looks like this

[image]

The problem is the new fixture comes with a mounting plate that would be mounted to a regular box but its too big for this box and besides, there is no room for the wires and nuts to fit in the ceiling even if i would just screw the mounting plate into the drywall. the old fixture had the wires and nuts outside the fixture in a cover that went flush with the ceiling. What are my options with this? Thanks.

---

[image]

So this is the new plate. The wire from the fixture which is not shown in the picture is supposed to feed through the center hole and then be connected above the plate with the connection in the ceiling. My friend had this idea of making a wider hole in this plate and feed the 2 electric wires from the ceiling down through the plate and wiring them to the fixture underneath the plate since there is no room for wires and nuts above the plate. My issue is the fixture has a dome cover that would hide the wires and nuts but it is a plastic cover. Is that an issue?

Comment: A picture of the new fixture box might help.

Comment: Is this house >100yo?  That just might be a gas nipple for the gas lights...

Comment: ceiling pan boxes are pretty small.  I'd be surprised if you can't fit two wire nuts into the space in the picture.  You think that is less space than this?  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-1-2-in-Deep-5-9-cu-in-Ceiling-Fan-Box-with-Metal-Cover-CMB50/205383205

Comment: To answer some of the comments. The house is over 100yo. The wires are the old braided type so  wouldn’t want to try and squeeze them into that little space and I don’t think they would fit. “Harper” is eight the original fixture had a dome cover that hid the wiring outside of the ceiling. The new plate is designed to have the wires in the ceiling.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

This type of fixture really assumes the lamp will have a "ceiling rose" or "dome" of some kind to provide room for the wiring.   If the mounting plate is flat, it may intend for you to bring those wires through large holes in the plate, and make the connections below the plate.